# How to get the simplest form of this radical expression: $3\sqrt[3]{2a} - 6\sqrt[3]{2a}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

How to get the simplest form of this radical expression: 
$$3\sqrt[3]{2a} - 6\sqrt[3]{2a}$$

Here is my work:
$$3\sqrt[3]{2a} - 6\sqrt[3]{2a}$$
Since the radicands are the same, we just add the coefficients. 
$$-3\sqrt[3]{2a} \sqrt[3]{2a}$$
Since everything is under the same index it becomes:
$$-3\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{a}$$

Did I do this correctly, if not can anyone tell me what I should do?
Thanks :-).

Comment: $-3\sqrt[3]{2a} \sqrt[3]{2a}$ is a typo (should be $-3\sqrt[3]{2a}$). You're answer is fine.

Comment: This question should be posted on MO :p

Comment: @metacompactness nah, i think it should be on MU, mathunderflow

Comment: @Lost1 There's almost no flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middle step is incorrect, it should be $-3\sqrt[3]{2a}$ not $-3\sqrt[3]{2a}\sqrt[3]{2a}$. It should be $$3\sqrt[3]{2a} - 6\sqrt[3]{2a} = 3\times\sqrt[3]{2a} - 6\times\sqrt[3]{2a} = (3 - 6)\times\sqrt[3]{2a} = -3\times\sqrt[3]{2a} = -3\sqrt[3]{2a}.$$ I don't think $-3\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt[3]{a}$ is any simpler than $-3\sqrt[3]{2a}$, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

We can factor, as an alternative, to get the same result:

$$3\sqrt[3]{2a} - 6\sqrt[3]{2a} = 3\sqrt[3]{2a}(1 - 2) = -3\sqrt[3]{2a}$$

(I don't see any need to write: $\;-3\sqrt[3]{2a} = -3\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{a})$

**Note** that $-3\sqrt[3]{2a}\sqrt[3]{2a} = -3\sqrt[3]{4a^2} \neq -3\sqrt[3]{2a} $

Answer (score 2):

$$3\sqrt[3]{2a}-6\sqrt[3]{2a}=\sqrt[3]{2a}(3-6)=\sqrt[3]{2a}(-3)= -3\sqrt[3]{2a}$$

Comment: $\ddot\smile{}{}{}$